# How can we get same channelID at all installation in UAPush plugin + phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I need channel-ID to send push notification by PhoneGap plugin in Android/iOS. I'm able to get channel-id same in iOS but Android gives different Channel-Id at all re-installation. I need same Channel-Id at all- reinstallation. Please help me if any one implemented it. Thanks a-lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have google but i got that , on each installation , app creates new channel ID. Please follow given link.
http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html
So, If we want to save and access first created channel-ID over re-installation, we should use permanent storage to store first generated channel-ID and access it at all installation.